# How to access dynamic route parameters when preloading server-side render

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side, redux-thunk

I am attempting to render a dynamic route preloaded with data fetched via an async `thunk`.

I have a static `initialAction` method in my Components that require preloading, and let them call the actions as needed.  Once all actions are done and promises are resolved, I render the route/page.

The question that I have is: how do I reference the route parameters and/or props inside a static function?

Here is the relevant code that will call any `initialAction` functions that may be required to preload data.

```
const promises = routes.reduce((promise, route) => {
    if (matchPath(req.url, route) && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
        promise.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction(store))))
    }
    return promise;
}, []);

Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => {
    // Do stuff, render, etc
})
```

In my component, I have the static `initialAction` function that will take in the store (from server), and props (from client).  One way or the other, the category should be fetched via redux/thunk.  As you can see, I'm not passing the dynamic `permalink` prop when loading via the server because I'm unable to retrieve it.

```
class Category extends Component {

    static initialAction(store, props) {
        let res = store !== null ? getCategory(REACT_APP_SITE_KEY) : props.getCategory(REACT_APP_SITE_KEY, props.match.params.permalink)
        return res
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(isEmpty(this.props.category.categories)){
            Category.initialAction(null, this.props)
        }
    }

    /* ... render, etc */
}
```

And finally, here are the routes I am using:

```
import Home from '../components/home/Home'
import Category from '../components/Category'
import Product from '../components/product/Product'
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound'

export default [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: "/category/:permalink",
        component: Category
    },
    {
        path: "/:category/product/:permalink",
        component: Product
    },
    {
        component: NotFound
    }
]
```

Not entirely sure I'm even doing this in a "standard" way, but this process works thus far when on a non-dynamic route.  However, I have a feeling I'm waaaay off base :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the server you have request object and on the client, you have location object. Extract url parameters from these objects after checking current environment.

```
const promises = routes.reduce((promise, route) => {
    var props = matchPath(req.url, route);
    if ( obj && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
        promise.push(Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction(store, props))))
    }
    return promise;
}, []);
```

now you will get url in initialAction in both desktop and server. you can extract dynamic route params from this

Comment: I attempted this, and it truly makes sense to me that it'd work as you described.  However when i tried to console.log() the new url parameter in initialAction, I still cannot access the params.  I updated my question with my routes.  Judging from my route I've matched, I should have a `category` parameter available.

Any idea why I may not?

Comment: what is printed when you do console.log(props) inside initialAction?

Comment: it should print the url. If it does, you can extract the params from there.

Comment: From the server, I pass in `req.url`.  Inside initialAction, it prints the url verbatim: `/category/hats`.  I feel like I'm missing something very very obvious.

Comment: A handy object!!!  I did not realize matchPath returned useful information. 
Thank you for all of your help :)